# Dismantling a rear view mirror to access mic/compass

Tags: electrical, mirrors

I have a 2012 Ford Mustang V6 Premium convertible, and it comes with a rear view mirror that contains a mic for voice-activated features and a compass.

I recently removed that mirror and replaced it with a mirror for a back-up camera system. However, this new mirror doesn't have the mic/compass, and I wanted to see if there was a way I could get those features back.

Does anyone know how to disassemble one of these rear view mirrors so I can access the hardware inside? I don't care too much if the mirror breaks in the process- I just want the hardware (mic/compass) to be intact).

Comment: Suggestion: glue the old mirror to the windshield, sort of behind the new one.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Weather Vane I think the mirror is just too bulky to do that. I actually ended up just cracking the mirror and pulling out the glass to get to the hardware. I took out the circuitboard and it looks like my mic/compass are still intact! Will glue that instead